# Excel vba copying and pasting based on cell value code not working

Tags: vba, excel

So im pretty new to VBA coding, and I'm trying to setup a commandbutton that when activated copys everything from sheet "Opties" to the sheet "BOM" from the column D and F that has a 1 in column with the titel "Totaal" and remove blanks.

So far this is my code

```
Sub Copy()
Dim c As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Optie")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("BOM")
Dim colNum As Integer

colNum = Worksheetfuntion.Match("Totaal", ws1.Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
c = 1
x = -4 + colNum
y = -6 + colNum
Set rng1 = ws1.Column(colNum)
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("C5:C25000")

For Each c In ws1.rng1

rng1.Offset(0, x).Copy
rng2.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng1.Offset(0, y).Copy
rng2.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: When tyring to loop in a range, like in your line `For Each c In ws1.rng1` . c needs to be defined as `Range`, where you have it as `Integer`. Also, since your `rng1` is fully qualified, you need to have it as `For Each c In rng1`

Comment: `For Each c In ws1.rng1` should be `For Each c In rng1` - `rng1` is not a Property or Method of the worksheet

Comment: `Set rng1 = ws1.Column(colNum)` needs to be `Set rng1 = ws1.Columns(colNum).Cells`

Comment: Reading the question again I don't think you need ranges at all. What you want is a loop. You want to loop through all rows, and check if the value for Totaal is 1. If so you want to copy the cells of that row and column D and Column F to a new worksheet. If you keep track of the last column there you can just increment.

Comment: I was just going to point out that you are never using the `c` object in any meaningful way - all your copies are based on the whole range - but I think the comment by @Luuklag covers that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code should work:

```
'Try to avoid using names that Excel uses - you will sometimes "block" the
'native function, so call the subroutine "myCopy" or something else, but
'preferably not "Copy"
Sub myCopy()
    Dim r1 As Long ' Use Long rather than Integer, because Excel
    Dim r2 As Long ' now allows for more than 65536 rows
    'Use Worksheets collection for worksheets, and only use the Sheets
    ' collection if you need to process Charts as well as Worksheets
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("Optie") 'Should this be "Opties"?
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("BOM")
    Dim colNum As Long

    colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("Totaal", ws1.Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
    r2 = 5 ' I guessed that 5 is the first row you want to write to

    'Loop through every row until the last non-empty row in Totaal column
    For r1 = 1 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
        'See if value in Totaal column is 1
        If ws1.Cells(r1, colNum).Value = 1 Then
            'I have guessed that your destination columns are D & E based on 
            'your Offset(0, 1) and Offset(0, 2) from column C
            'I have guessed that your source columns are F & D based on the
            'question mentioning those columns, and the offsets of -4 and -6
            'in your current code - I assume based on "Totaal" being column J
            'Change my guesses as necessary

            'Copy values to destination from source
            ws2.Cells(r2, "D").Value = ws1.Cells(r1, "F").Value
            ws2.Cells(r2, "E").Value = ws1.Cells(r1, "D").Value
            'Increment row counter for destination sheet
            r2 = r2 + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks for your help, however it gives me the error "Object required". Also all of your assumptions were correct! Im just not very good at VBA so i'm learning along the way.

Comment: Maybe I should also point out that everyhing in cell "Totaal" is actually a value that gets changed with a function? So there is function in that cell determaning if it should be 0 or 1.

Comment: @Dubzmeister - LOL - It's always the way - there was about one line of your original code left when I finished changing things ... and it had a typo (`Worksheetfuntion` should have been `WorksheetFunction`).  Answer edited.  The way the value in the cells in column Totaal is determined won't affect the code - it just looks to see if the `Value` is 1 or not.  (Unless you mean you want a `Worksheet_Change` event to detect when the cell changes value and automatically copy things if it changes to 1?)

Comment: @Dubzmeister - I just changed the `Sub` name too - I think that leaves just the `End Sub` untouched.  I wonder what reason I can come up with to change it somehow!  :D

Comment: Thank you so so much! It did exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @Dubzmeister Good - time for me to pack it in for the night now.